# Prevent wrapping in flex items

Tags: css, flexbox

I have two flexbox items next to each other.  The left item contains text and must never wrap.  The right item contains svgs and I want these svgs to resize as per the available space.  I can't get it working.

This is what I have but as you can see the text wraps:

[image]

```css
.container {
  width: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 2px blue solid;
  
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap; /* has no effect */
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.nowrap {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  margin-right: 15px;
}

.images {
/*   flex: 0 0 auto; unsure of this */
  display: flex;
  max-height: 80px;
}

img {
  min-width: 0;
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <span class="nowrap">Never wrap</span>
  <div class="images">
    <img src="https://assets.codepen.io/3/kiwi.svg" />
    <img src="https://assets.codepen.io/3/kiwi.svg" />
    <img src="https://assets.codepen.io/3/kiwi.svg" />
    <img src="https://assets.codepen.io/3/kiwi.svg" />
  <div>
</div>
```

I've started a [CodePen](https://codepen.io/benrich/pen/RwgmXoO) with different (but similar) markup.  In there I would assuming `flex: 1 1 auto;` means that that flex item has 'priority' and won't wrap.  But because it's not working I suspect I have a fundamental misunderstanding of flexbox.  (and maybe svgs are making it extra complicated as svgs are documents, not images)

As a bonus question.  I want left & right flexboxes to be pushed part (`justify-content: space-between`) and in case the container width is really big, apply a `max-height` or `max-width` on the svgs.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's nothing in your `nowrap` class instructing the text not to wrap.

It's just this:

```
.nowrap {
   flex: 1 1 auto;
   margin-right: 15px;
}
```

Add this:

```
.nowrap {
   flex: 1 1 auto;
   margin-right: 15px;
   white-space: nowrap;
   align-self: center; /* optional */
}
```

Comment: Well I feel stupid.  There's me getting transfixed on flex-wrap, which now I realise has nothing to do with what I wanted.  Thanks Michael